# How should I deal with '_id' in Dataclass when used in combination with MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-dataclasses

I have a MongoDB and would like to store each document as an instance of a python dataclass. I have a problem with the '_id'. When I create a local instance, I don't want to allocate an '_id'. However, when retrieving a document, the instance should contain the '_id'.

My approach was to set the '_id' as None. This does not work when I insert an instance into the database. The value `None` is passed as '_id'.

Is there a way to create a model with dataclass which allows me to store the local and retrieved data as instances of the same class?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass 
from typing import List

from bson import ObjectId

@dataclass
class Article:
    name: str
    quantity: int
    _id: ObjectId = None
    description: str = ""
```

**Insert local instance**

```py
import dataclasses
from pymongo import MongoClient

article = Article(name="pen", description="A writing device", quantity=100)

self.client = MongoClient()
self.db = self.client.warehouse
self.collection = self.db["articles"]
res = self.collection.insert_one(dataclasses.asdict(article)) # <-- Should not contain "_id"
```

**Retrieve document**

```
res = self.collection.find_one("_id": ObjectID())
article = Article(**res) # <-- Article should contain id
```

Comment: What happens if you do not set _id?

Comment: If I do not set the '_id' the default which is `None` is set and is submitted to the database.

Comment: How does that differ from what you want?

Comment: I would like MongoDB to create an ObjectId. This is the default behaviour of Mongo. This unique id is then used to find it again.

Comment: All documents in the server are supposed to have an _id field on them, are you successfully inserting a document without an _id?

Comment: Yes, the insertion works as expected when I remove _id from the dataclass. Then the retrieval doesn't work anymore because the __init__() gets one attribute too much: '_id'

Comment: I'm guessing you need to have the _id field defined. What happens when you use pymongo to insert a document where _id is explicitly set to None?

Comment: None is set as _id.

Comment: If you are claiming that document is persisted without id, please provide mongo shell output demonstrating that.

Comment: What you maybe would need to  do is write the _id into your class explicitly in the constructor.

Comment: Why not use the [ObjectId](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html#module-bson.objectid) methods to create a unique value for _id instead of using None?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to come up with a more general solution:

I made an interface `MongoDataclass` from which all my models inherit. The interface contains a method which returns all key value pairs where the value is not `None` as a dict.

In my opinion this makes sense since MongoDB is schemaless and I don't want to store any `None` values in my documents. This also solves the problem with the '_id'.

```
import abc
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MongoDataclass(abc.ABC):

    def as_json_wo_none(self):
        return {key: value for key, value in dataclasses.asdict(self).items() if value is not None}
```

Comment: 1.`{key: value for key, value in dataclasses.asdict(self).items() if value is not None}`   2. And no need to inherit from `abc.ABC`

Comment: I agree on your first point (corrected my answer). Why should I remove the abstract base class?  I want all dataclasses which are used in combination with Mongo to inherit from this abstract base class.

Comment: `abc.ABC` is useless since there are no abstract methods in your class

Comment: I might have other fields having  None as value I could be interested on. Your solution does more (not always desirable) than just solving the `_id` issue.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Article:
    name: str
    quantity: int
    id: Optional[int] = None
    description: str = ''

    def to_short_dict(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop('id')
        return result


# not contain "id"
input_data = {
    'name': 'pen', 'quantity': 100, 'description': 'A writing device',
}
article = Article(**input_data)
assert article.to_short_dict() == input_data

# contain "id"
input_data = {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'pen', 'quantity': 100, 'description': 'A writing device',
}
article = Article(**input_data)
assert asdict(article) == input_data
```

Comment: I like the idea with the function. I am looking for a more general solution.